# Why my project-level build.gradle in Android Studio is different that it is supposed to be?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I was trying to build a note-taking app according to this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or_pH92l-IQ

I followed this tutorial step-by-step, but my project-level build.gradle is
[my_build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwzc7.png)
, which is different from the one in the video:
[tutorial_build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYHGe.png).

After some online research, I found from
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-build-gradle/
that all Android projects in Java seem to start with such a build.gradle when they are created. However, mine is just different.

Any idea about why is this happening, and how I can get the correct build.gradle generated?

I have been an EE person and know very little about coding, so please don't go harsh. Thank you!

Comment: you have an updated version build.gradle thats' why.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking your `build.gradle` that have the label `(Project: YourAppName)`
please check `build.gradle` that have a label `(Module: YourAppName)` like this:

[image]

Comment: But I'm comparing my build.gradle(Project: AppName) with tutorial's build.gradle(Project: AppName), and they are the root build.gradle; module-level build.gradle is irrelevant to this problem, right?

Comment: I think for now you are using build.gradle for some library integration ie: example `implementation:'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'` right!

Comment: in the tutorial, they have added `jcenter` you don't need to add `jcenter` that is already added. and for your information, `jcenter` will be going to shut down soon.

Comment: Yes, there are several lines of `implementation 'something'` in the `dependencies { ... }` part of my build.gradle (Module), but how's that relate to my problem?